# Ajax action link opens new page instead showing alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have an Ajax action link.

```
        @Ajax.ActionLink(item.sifra_materijala,   
                            "DetaljiMaterijala", 
                            "NormativiMaterijala", 
                            new { materijal = item.sifra_materijala.ToString() },
                            new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "success", UpdateTargetId = "ListaMaterijala" },
                            new { Id = item.sifra_materijala })
```

HTML generated by this link is:

```
<a href="/NormativiMaterijala/DetaljiMaterijala?materijal=070215" data-ajax-update="#ListaMaterijala" data-ajax-success="success" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax="true" id="070215">070215</a>
```

This link call controller action

```
    [HttpGet]
    public virtual JsonResult DetaljiMaterijala(string materijal) 
    {


        var mat = (from m in db.materijalis
                   where m.sifra_materijala == materijal
                   select m);


        return Json(new { sifra_materijala = mat.First().ime_materijala }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);}
```

and success js function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function success() {
        alert("result is success");
    };
</script>
```

but when i click on link, instead of an alert, new page opens in browser with an action result. I have js unobtrusive an jquery scripts included on the page with

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: try `return false` from the click event of the <a

Comment: Try loading the ajax script after you load jQuery. Also you only need one of those Bootstrap files - probably best loading just the minified one.